# Loading dynamic theme liferay

Tags: dynamic, liferay-6, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

There are two themes, I want to change dynamically from portal_normal.vm or from java in doView function. is it possible?

I have two domains with only one portal and I want to change depending url.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? It's quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

**portal_normal.vm**
 is a theme related file description.
You can create two communities ( or two pages) and assign a theme for every one of them.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a default Theme associated for every Site and it will act as a Default Look and Feel for all Layouts inside a Site/Community, if you have not updated it through Layout.

If you want to use a different Layout at run time, Just check the LayoutLocalServiceUtil class.

Check http://digitalfireflymarketing.com/how-select-multiple-themes-liferay for details